# Moving TIMESTAMP column from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, ssms

I have an Oracle DB with some data that I want to move to a SQL Server.

Problem is that my Oracle DB have some columns with the type `TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE` and SSIS detects thous as `CLOB`. So it fails saying it cannot convert `CLOB` to `datetime2`.

I've already created the tables inside the SQL Server database. So it's just moving the data over with some type conversion.

I'm using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard (SSIS) from SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

I'm using the **.NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle** to connect to the Oracle DB and the **SQL Server Native Client 11.0** to connect to my SQL Server.

My source type is `TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE` and my destination type is `datetime2`.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
[Source Information]
Source Location : localhost
Table: "MYSPACE"."MYTABLE"
Column: START_DATE
Column Type: CLOB
SSIS Type: Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT]
Mapping file (to SSIS type): C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\MappingFiles\OracleClientToSSIS10.XML

[Destination Information]
Destination Location : localhost
Destination Provider : SQLNCLI11
Table: [dbo].[mytable]
Column: start_date
Column Type: datetime2
SSIS Type: database timestamp with precision [DT_DBTIMESTAMP2]
Mapping file (to SSIS type): C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\MappingFiles\MSSQLToSSIS10.XML

[Conversion Steps]
Conversion unknown ...
SSIS conversion file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\binn\DtwTypeConversion.xml
```

So as you can see the `START_DATE` column is detected as a CLOB. This is incorrect.

I looked inside OracleClientToSSIS10.XML

```
<!-- TIMESTAMP 10.* -->
<dtm:DataTypeMapping >
    <dtm:SourceDataType>
        <dtm:DataTypeName>timestamp</dtm:DataTypeName>
    </dtm:SourceDataType>
    <dtm:DestinationDataType>
        <dtm:NumericType>
            <dtm:DataTypeName>DT_DBTIMESTAMP2</dtm:DataTypeName>
            <dtm:SkipPrecision/>
            <dtm:UseSourceScale/>
        </dtm:NumericType>
    </dtm:DestinationDataType>
</dtm:DataTypeMapping>  

<!-- TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 10.* -->
<dtm:DataTypeMapping >
    <dtm:SourceDataType>
        <dtm:DataTypeName>TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE</dtm:DataTypeName>
    </dtm:SourceDataType>
    <dtm:DestinationDataType>
        <dtm:NumericType>
            <dtm:DataTypeName>DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET</dtm:DataTypeName>
            <dtm:SkipPrecision/>
            <dtm:UseSourceScale/>
        </dtm:NumericType>
    </dtm:DestinationDataType>
</dtm:DataTypeMapping>  

<!-- CLOB -->
<dtm:DataTypeMapping >
    <dtm:SourceDataType>
        <dtm:DataTypeName>CLOB</dtm:DataTypeName>
    </dtm:SourceDataType>
    <dtm:DestinationDataType>
        <dtm:CharacterStringType>
            <dtm:DataTypeName>DT_NTEXT</dtm:DataTypeName>
            <dtm:Length>255</dtm:Length>
        </dtm:CharacterStringType>
    </dtm:DestinationDataType>
</dtm:DataTypeMapping>
```

Seems fine, right?

Comment: Not an Oracle person but the difference between their date/time representation and SQL Server's is/was a known incompatibility. Without seeing examples of what the data actually looks like, I would assume the source values have actual offset values in them `-05:00` which won't map into a datetime2. I would do the equivalent of casting the date in Oracle as a character field with the format of `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ms` and have Oracle also handle the timezone. Otherwise, you'll need to change the target type in SQL Server to be `datetimeoffset` and then include offset info in the string for SSIS

Comment: For testing purposes I added a `TIMESTAMP` (no timezone) column with NULL values and tried to map that to a `datetime2` column in MSSQL. It was still being detected as a `CLOB` column. So think the actual values are irrelevant at this stage.

Comment: The .NET framework provider for Oracle that comes with the framework is out of date and unsupported -- it's essentially not been updated since it was first included. Use Oracle's own provider. If all else fails, a fairly simple workaround would be to convert the data type in Oracle first through a query or view, to whatever data type works (if you're using `DATETIME2` as the destination rather than `DATETIMEOFFSET` you presumably don't need the time zone info, for starters, so a plain `TIMESTAMP` on the Oracle side should also do).

Comment: The first step to resolve this will be to get SSIS to not detect your incoming column as CLOB/DT_NTEXT. That's why I indicated you should use the Oracle equivalent to convert the datetime to a string in the ISO format. The SSIS engine will then detect that DT_STR/DT_WSTR and then the provider that pushes your data into the destination *should* have the smarts to translate to the target format.

Comment: Not sure if it works with the Import/Export wizard, but Microsoft distributes an Oracle Connector by Attunity that is superior to both Oracle's and SQL Server's native connectors. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/attunity-connectors?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I can't get the Attunity Oracle driver to show up in the Import/Export wizard so I'm guess it isn't supported :(

Comment: It should show up as `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle`. I've also verified that I can use it in the Import/Export wizard.

Answer (score 4):

I've had similar problems dealing with Oracle-formatted date-ish datatypes. What I've found that works is to convert the data to a string on the Oracle side before pulling it across. Then you can transform the data once you get it into your SQL Server.

You'll want to modify the import/export wizard to use a query to specify the data to fetch from the Oracle server. As part of your source query, you can do the conversion like this:

```
SELECT
CAST("START_DATE" AS VARCHAR2(26)) AS "StartDate"
FROM MYSPACE.MYTABLE
```

Then in SQL Server, you can convert to a datetime like this:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, StartDate) AS DATETIME)
```

If you're on SQL Server 2016 or later, you can use `AT TIME ZONE` and your local timezone to get the adjusted datetime value:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, StartDate) AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any of the drivers to work for the date columns.

So I ended up going into SQL Developer and exporting the tables with date column to INSERT statements and then running regex replace on that.

Fun times :(

Answer (score 0):

This answer is overdue, but at least I can add a working solution to this particular task. I had to do a task that was almost identical to yours, the only differences were the database versions and source data types (I had a `TIMESTAMP` with no time zone). I ran into the same driver error, failing to convert `CLOB` to `datetime2`.

**Preface & Error Explanation**

I noticed your source datatype, `TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE`, stores the time zone whereas your destination datatype, `datetime2`, does not. It doesn't really affect the conversion steps too much, but something to keep in mind.

In my troubleshooting, I also saw the `OracleClientToSSIS10.XML` file, and saw the same details you listed in your post. At first I thought the `timestamp` entry was invalid because it wasn't uppercase, but I confirmed it does work.

With the file import wizard, the importer will read from the source, bind to an SSIS datatype, convert to an intermittent SSIS datatype, then convert to a valid destination datatype. You'll have to look at it from SSIS's perspective when you read the error messages.

The `OracleClientToSSIS10.XML` is really what the file importer uses to bind the source datatype to a valid SSIS datatype. What looks like happened to you is that the source data type didn't exactly match what the importer expects for that data type, so it went with the next best thing, CLOB, which maps to DT_NTEXT. To see what the importer expects for `DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET`,  go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15#conversion-of-data-types).

But this isn't what caused your error. If you look at the bottom of the error message, it lists `DtwTypeConversion.xml` This is the file that converts between SSIS datatypes.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn\DtwTypeConversion.xml

(filtered to just DT_NTEXT)

```
  <!-- Convert from DT_TEXT-->
  <dtw:ConversionEntry>
    <dtw:SourceType>DT_TEXT</dtw:SourceType>
    <dtw:DestinationType TypeName="DT_STR">
      <dtw:ConversionStep StepNum="1" ConvertToType="DT_STR"/>
    </dtw:DestinationType>
    <dtw:DestinationType TypeName="DT_WSTR">
      <dtw:ConversionStep StepNum="1" ConvertToType="DT_STR"/>
      <dtw:ConversionStep StepNum="2" ConvertToType="DT_WSTR"/>
    </dtw:DestinationType>
    <dtw:DestinationType TypeName="DT_IMAGE">
      <dtw:ConversionStep StepNum="1" ConvertToType="DT_IMAGE"/>
    </dtw:DestinationType>
    <dtw:DestinationType TypeName="DT_NTEXT">
      <dtw:ConversionStep StepNum="1" ConvertToType="DT_NTEXT"/>
    </dtw:DestinationType>
  </dtw:ConversionEntry>

  
  <!-- Convert from DT_NTEXT-->
  <dtw:ConversionEntry>
    <dtw:SourceType>DT_NTEXT</dtw:SourceType>
    <dtw:DestinationType TypeName="DT_STR">
      <dtw:ConversionStep StepNum="1" ConvertToType="DT_WSTR"/>
      <dtw:ConversionStep StepNum="2" ConvertToType="DT_STR"/>
    </dtw:DestinationType>
    <dtw:DestinationType TypeName="DT_WSTR">
      <dtw:ConversionStep StepNum="1" ConvertToType="DT_WSTR"/>
    </dtw:DestinationType>
    <dtw:DestinationType TypeName="DT_IMAGE">
      <dtw:ConversionStep StepNum="1" ConvertToType="DT_IMAGE"/>
    </dtw:DestinationType>
    <dtw:DestinationType TypeName="DT_TEXT">
      <dtw:ConversionStep StepNum="1" ConvertToType="DT_TEXT"/>
    </dtw:DestinationType>
  </dtw:ConversionEntry>
```

If you look under `<!-- Convert from DT_NTEXT-->` block, you'll notice that there's no subtree for `DT_DBTIMESTAMP2`, which means there's no conversion from `DT_NTEXT` to `DT_DBTIMESTAMP2`. This is what caused the error (`DT_DBTIMESTAMP2` is the SSIS equivalent of datetime2; you can verify it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15#mapping-of-integration-services-data-types-to-database-data-types)).

**How to Fix the Problem**
You will need to either:

1. get the importer to recognize `DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET`. To be honest, I don't think you'll get them to match up, others have stated the date time conversions have been incompatible or tricky
2. change your source query to pre-convert the `TIMESTAMP` into a string, then have the importer convert it to a `datetime2`. When you do this, you must ensure the DtwTypeConversion.xml file has a conversion from the string you chose, to the `DT_DBTIMESTAMP2`

**System versions of listed solutions**

Source database: Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2.0)

- Data types: mostly varchar2, numeric, and one field with timestamp(2) (no time zone)

Destination database: Microsoft SQL Server 2019

- Data types: smaller fields (varchar2 reduced, some were turned into char, some numeric were turned into int or smallint or tinyint). The timestamp field was turned into datetime2

SSMS: 18.9.1

**Solution #1: Use SSMS - SQL Server Import and Export Wizard - Oracle Driver**

1. Open up DtwTypeConversion.xml, go to the section where it says `<!-- Convert from DT_NTEXT-->`, and add a subtree, then save

   ```
      <!-- Convert from DT_WSTR-->
      <dtw:ConversionEntry>
        <dtw:SourceType>DT_WSTR</dtw:SourceType>
        <dtw:DestinationType TypeName="DT_I1">
          <dtw:ConversionStep StepNum="1" ConvertToType="DT_I1"/>
        </dtw:DestinationType>
   ```

   ...

   ```
        <dtw:DestinationType TypeName="DT_DBTIME">
          <dtw:ConversionStep StepNum="1" ConvertToType="DT_DBTIME"/>
        </dtw:DestinationType>
        <dtw:DestinationType TypeName="DT_DBTIMESTAMP">
          <dtw:ConversionStep StepNum="1" ConvertToType="DT_DBTIMESTAMP"/>
        </dtw:DestinationType>
        <dtw:DestinationType TypeName="DT_DBTIMESTAMP2">
          <dtw:ConversionStep StepNum="1" ConvertToType="DT_DBTIMESTAMP2"/>
        </dtw:DestinationType>
        <dtw:DestinationType TypeName="DT_FILETIME">
          <dtw:ConversionStep StepNum="1" ConvertToType="DT_FILETIME"/>
        </dtw:DestinationType>
   ```
2. Source driver:

- `.NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle` - ended up using this one, because it worked, was easy to build the connection string, and it required the least amount of effort to do the data type conversion.
- `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle` - This one could work, but the login procedure doesn't always work and it kept giving me problems with the text fields being Unicode/non-Unicode
- `Oracle Provider for OLE DB` - This one kept giving me errors with number conversions, so more effort to use

2. Destination driver:

- `SQL Server Native Client 11.0`

3. Create a source query that will convert the timestamp to a character, something akin to

   ```
    select
        allOtherFields
        ,TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP '2021-08-02 14:30:20.05 -05:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF7') as converted_str
    from mySchema.myTable
   ```

- To test just a subset, you can add a `FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY` after your table name

4. When you review the mapping, you should see the timestamp field pass checks without any errors
5. Run and import

**Solution #2: Use SSMS - SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, Flat File Source**

1. Create a query that will convert the timestamp to a character, something akin to

   ```
    select
    allOtherFields
    --,TIMESTAMP '2021-08-02 14:30:20.05 -05:00' as original_timestamp_with_zone
    ,TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP '2021-08-02 14:30:20.05 -05:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF7') as converted_str
    from mySchema.MyTable;
   ```

- To test just a subset, you can add a `FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY` after your table name
- Make sure the string output matches exactly to the datetime2 field you are going to. The example above should suffice

2. Save the query output to a csv file, it's a good idea to use a text qualifier
3. Source driver:

- `Flat File Source`

  - Ensure you set a text qualifier
  - Ensure the time column gets set as a string, or DT_WSTR

4. Destination driver:

- `SQL Server Native Client 11.0`

5. When you review the mapping, you should see the timestamp field pass checks without any errors
6. Run and import

**Alternative: Use SSMA tool**

The [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/migrating-oracle-databases-to-sql-server-oracletosql?view=sql-server-ver15) will be a good guide for this.
At first it seemed straightforward, but I ended up having to do quite a bit of code to prep the tables, as the code snippets generated don't get the indexes right and the data file would always default to [PRIMARY]
Even after all the coding, I ended up scrapping this method because I was getting too many row errors and didn't get much info beyond the "table was partially processed". If you're just migrating smaller tables without much data type conversion, you'll be fine